# How can I change preview URL?

Tags: wp-config, previews

How can I change the preview URL in Wordpress?

When creating a post in Wordpress, there is a `Preview` button which takes you to the draft view. Because I have a custom integration of Wordpress and don't use a theme, I would like to change the URL of the preview link. Is this possible? How?

Regarding the custom implementation, Wordpress posts are integrated in another framework. I do this by setting `WP_USE_THEMES` to `false`, loading `wp-config.php` and directly accessing the posts using `WP_Query()`.  This means I am bypassing any Wordpress theme that is set.

Comment: You can try the preview_post_link filter: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_preview_post_link/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do something like this, add to functions.php

```
add_filter( 'preview_post_link', 'the_preview_fix' );

function the_preview_fix() {
    $slug = basename(get_permalink());
    return "http://www.mywebsite.com/blog/p/$slug";
}
```

More info [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8741485/wordpress-preview-post-link) and [HERE](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/php-wordpress-change-post-url-via-preview_post_link-filter/).

Comment: How do you deploy one of these?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Through the above code we can surly update the URL/permalink of the Preview Changes button, but this new link can't hold the temporary changes for the current page/post. The default preview links has preview id and nonce value to hold the temporary changes for the page/post but if we are updating the structure, so the new structure are not able to hold the temporary changes for the pages/post. Looking for solution to keep changes as well for the pages/post like default preview link.